# I am getting 80% time error on running protractor scripts on IE 11

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

My protractor scripts are highly stable on chrome browser but the same scripts throws below mentioned for 20% of the test cases.

Failed: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 100 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
    System info: host: 'LAPTOP-RNQ2JQBE', ip: '192.168.89.115', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=true, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:41897/, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
    Session ID: f32d0eb8-65d9-4161-9535-da5cde8b9a6c

> Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page:
>   "Unable to get property '$$testability' of undefined or null
>   reference"

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?